# EMR Notebook Access HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

If I am in an EMR notebook and save a model like .save('model.sav') where does it save and how would I reference it with hdfs dfs commands (the hdfs path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give an absolute save path instead but by default, it should go under the HDFS /home folder for the user account running the notebook

Comment: So .save('/home/model.sav') should then be retrievable using hdfs://home/model.sav?

Comment: No. There's a username after the home folder. Inside that would be the model. For example /home/ec2-user/model.sav

Comment: Oddly, when accessing with an EMR notebook, this directory doesnt appear to be set up. I cant SSH into the master at the moment either given some security issues

Comment: Like I said, that's only an example. I don't know what HDFS/Unix user account your EMR notebooks use